# APK packages is not served in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to serve `.apk` files in my ASP.NET Core MVC project, and I can't since it returns 404.

I created a simple ASP.NET Core MVC project using default template in VS 2017, and added the `.apk` file to `wwwroot` folder, and then I tried to reach it using `/application.apk` path, and it didn't work, while `/favicon.ico` works, and other static contents in that directory work, because in default template `app.UseStaticFiles()` is  called.

I then tried to change configurations, brought static contents out of `wwwroot` folder and put the `application.apk` in the root directory of the project (one folder up from `wwwroot`) and configured the project using:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
});
```

Again no result. I get 404.

Then I created a `Web.config` file and added this MIME Type:

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
</staticContent>
```

Still, doesn't serve the `.apk` file.

What should I do?

Answer (score 18):

The ASP.NET Core Static files middleware apparently doesn't serve files which don't have a mapping to a MIME type in the `ContentTypeProvider`. To solve this, you should add the MIME mapping to the `ContentTypeProvider`:

```
    FileExtensionContentTypeProvider contentTypes = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
    contentTypes.Mappings[".apk"] = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        ContentTypeProvider = contentTypes
    });
```

Now the `.apk` will be served.

Comment: where we should add this?

Comment: you should add this in the Startup class, where the middlewares are registered (see the UseStaticFiles line)

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to giving it work

In your Startup.cs file's Configure method, make the following changes:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
    　 { 
         ".apk",
         "application/vnd.android.package-archive"
       }
    })
});
```