# How to serve android application from ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, apk

Is it possible to use this URL `domain.tld/android_application_name.apk` to serve an Android application `apk` file from `AndroidApplications` directory?

In other words, I have a folder sibling to `Controllers` folder and `wwwroot` folder and `Program.cs` file. It's called `AndroidApplications` and inside it I have a bunch of `.apk` files. But I don't want to add an extra segment to the URL for them. I want to be able to serve `app1.apk` via this URL: `domain.tld/app1.apk`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you tried reading the docs and the static files middleware? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: @Tseng, thanks for the link. Yeah I've read that. My case is very special and I've done many things to make it work. Yet it doesn't. Please see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49402090/apk-packages-is-not-served-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

Comment: I don't see **anything** special about serving a static file from an ASP.NET Core application and nothing in your question hints that there is some special requirement and **WHICH** requirement that may be. With static files middleware any file located in wwwroot folder can be served back as download as long as it exists (and if registered before other middlewares, registration order matters)

Comment: @Tseng, if you read the question carefully, my `.apk` files are located inside another folder. And to serve from another folder, we need a path segment to be specified. In other words, you can't serve `/something.jpg` from another folder. You need to serve it via `/some-path-segment/something.jpg`. But I already have my URLs published to other places, so I can't prefix them.

Comment: Did u get this working i think the term u mean is provision. I am wanting to do same with customers app

Comment: @csharpdude77, yeah I did it. but I don't remember it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the [Url Rewriting Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x).

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    var options = new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRewrite(@"^(.*?\.apk)$", "AndroidApplications/$1", 
            skipRemainingRules: true)

    app.UseRewriter(options);
}
```

This should rewrite all urls ending with `apk`, i.e. from `/myapp.apk` urls to `/AndroidApplications/myapp.apk`.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a few answers like:
1) add ".apk" extension and correspoding mime type in IIS

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFLcY.png)

2) add below node in system.webServer node of web.config

But neither works.

So I found another solution and it works for me

3) set ServeUnknowFileType of StaticFileOptions to true in the Configure method of Startup

var staticFileOptions =
                new StaticFileOptions
                {
                    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
                };

```
        app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);
```

But I'm worried about the security issue.

Also the above two solutions might be for windows only, it will still be an issue when migrated to linux, correct me if I'm wrong.